# Remove checkbox from QErrorMessage

Tags: qt, checkbox

writing in QT and *QErrorMessage* by default has checkbox saying:

> Show this message again

Is there some way to remove this checkbox, so user won't be able to turn off this message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `QErrorMessage` use [`QMessageBox::critical`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagebox.html#critical) or [`QMessageBox::warning`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagebox.html#warning).

If you need to customise the message box further you can create an instance of `QMessageBox` and then `exec` it.

Comment: These links don't work currently.

Comment: @openCivilisation Links updated

Answer (score 2):

You can use a QMessageBox with adding your detailed error information with setDetailedText()

I guess the real deal of using QErrorMessage is the "don't show again" option.

didn't test it but here is the idea;

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
 msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error!");
 msgBox.setText("Short description");
 msgBox.setDetailedText("Detailed error Information");
 msgBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the copy paste ability that QErrorMessage would have, you could create your own custom QDialog. First I would make a dialog.ui with a QTextEdit (textEdit) and a QPushButton (okButton). Make sure you name the dialog object in the .ui something meaningful (MessageDialog in this case). The code could be something like this:

In your messagedialog.h:

```
class MessageDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::MessageDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui::MessageDialog *ui;

public:
    MessageDialog(QWidget * parent = 0, QString msg = "", uint w = 200, uint h = 100);

private slots:

    void on_okButton_clicked();

};
```

In your messagedialog.cpp:

```
MessageDialog::MessageDialog(QWidget *parent, QString msg, uint w, uint h) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::MessageDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setFixedSize(w, h);
    this->ui->textEdit->setFixedSize( (w - 20), (h - 50) );
    this->ui->textEdit->setGeometry( (this->geometry().left() + 10), 10, (ui->okButton->size().width()), (ui->okButton->size().height()));

    // I personally like to get rid of the ? next to close in the upper right, minimize, and maximize
    this->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
    this->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
    this->setWindowTitle("Message");
    this->ui->textEdit->setText(msg);
    this->ui->okButton->setGeometry( (this->geometry().center().x() - (this->ui->okButton->width() / 2) ), (this->geometry().bottom() - (this->ui->okButton->height())) - 5, (ui->okButton->size().width()), (ui->okButton->size().height()));
    this->setFocus();
}

void MessageDialog::on_okButton_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

Then wherever you want to use it:

```
QDialog *messageDialog = new MessageDialog(this, msg);

messageDialog->exec();
```